# How can I insert thousands of Woocommerce products by batch with PHP?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I have about 5000 products in Excel format to be uploaded thru HTML-PHP to Woocommerce db, how can I do this in the most optimal way, thru API / Direct DB or both?

**Clarification:** I don't want to use the built in, I need it as a PHP code so that I could add custom functionality upon import (like I need to log the products new/updated/imported on a custom table).

Comment: You mean, like my answer? ;)

Answer (score 3):

What's keeping you from using the [officially documented way to import products from csv](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/product-csv-importer-exporter/)? If you're running on an older version, there's [an extension](https://woocommerce.com/products/product-csv-import-suite/) that does the same thing.

Comment: I don't want to use the built in, I need it as a PHP code so that I could add custom functionality upon import (like I need to log the products new/updated/imported on a custom table).

Comment: There are hooks you can use for custom actions. Have you tried it?

Comment: The goal is to create a new plugin out of it. I apologize but I'm scrounging the documentation but can't find the code used in the importation of CSV for use in PHP for now.

Comment: See under FAQ, which leads to an example at github. `/includes/admin/importers/class-wc-product-csv-importer-controller.php` is the file in question, just look for apply_filters.

Answer (score 2):

While it's possible to insert the data directly into the Database, it's pretty much work and an error in the insertion / changes in the dataset structure would render the import completely useless, the API would be the better and safer way to insert the products.

However, 5000 Products are a lot, and using one function to insert them all could easily outrun the PHP Execution Time limit. So, if you use a "manual" importer (e.g. you click a button and the import runs), the best way of action would be to create an admin screen that works in two steps.

Step 1: Import the CSV and read the datasets. Save the datasets to a temporary database table or a table on the admin screen.

Step 2: Write an Ajax-Function to import 1 Product on the admin screen by API. Include information about which product was successfully (or unsuccessfully) imported in the returned data.

Step 3: Write a jQuery each function that sends only 1 Product at a time to the Ajax-Import-Function. You can use the jQuery timing plugin to ensure that one product each x milliseconds is sent via ajax. Start the function by a click. Now you just have to wait until all the products are imported. If you throw in a progress-bar, you will have a nice visual feedback how many products are imported yet.

The pasted code below is just a general idea of how you can accomplish that. Be aware that the parts where you actually DO SOMETHING with your data is not in it as i a) don't know how your CSV-File is built and b) am too lazy to look up how the woocommerce api works exactly.

```
<?php
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_menu_page_for_big_import');

function add_menu_page_for_big_import() {
    add_menu_page('Import all the products', 'Imports', 'manage_options', 'product-imports', 'all_the_products_import_output','dashicons-welcome-add-page' ,22);
}

function all_the_products_import_output(){
    wp_enqueue_media();
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-timing','http://creativecouple.github.io/jquery-timing/jquery-timing.min.js',array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-progressbar');
    wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui-smoothness-style','http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css');
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
    <?php 
     if(isset($_POST['filename'])) {
    //do whatever you need to do with the csv. Import it, put it in an array
    ?>
    <table class="imports">
        <?php
        $import_counter = 0;
        foreach($product_array as $product){
            $import_counter++;
            ?>
            <tr data-prodnumber="<?php echo $product['product_number']; ?>">
                <?php
                foreach($product as $key => $productfield){
                    ?>
                    <td class="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $productfield; ?></td>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </table>
    <span class="importpreview"><?php echo $import_counter; ?> Products for import.</span>
    <p>Click the button to start the import. Don't close the window until import is finished.</p>
    <div id="progressbar"></div>
    <p>
        <a class="button goimport" href="#" id="import_start">Start import</a>  
    </p>
    <span class="resultlabel">Result: </span><br />
    <span class="result" data-errors="0" data-imported="0">
        Products imported: <span class="updated">0</span><br />
        Errors: <span class="error">0</span>
    </span><br />
    <script>
        var progressbar;
        var aktval = 0;
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            progressbar = $('#progressbar').progressbar({
                max: <?php echo $import_counter; ?>
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
     } else {
    ?>
    <h2>Import Products</h2>
<form name="import_form" method="post" action="<?php echo str_replace( '%7E', '~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>">
    <label for="filename">CSV-File</label>
    <input id="upload_txt" type="text" name="filename" value="" />
    <input id="upload_button" type="button" value="upload csv file" />
    <input type="submit" value="next step" />
</form>
<?php } ?>
<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('.goimport').click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                var mycounter = 0;
                $('table.importdata tr').each($).wait(500,function(){
                    //by using the wait command (supplied by the jquery timing plugin), we ensure that not all the
                    //products are sent at once, but only every .5 seconds
                    mycounter++;
                    postdata = new Object();
                    postdata['action'] = 'import_all_the_products_action';
                    //put into the postdata all the data from the table you need like this:
                    postdata['keyname'] = $(this).find('td.keyname').html();
                        $.post(ajaxurl, postdata, function(response){
                            if(response.message == 'SUCCESS'){
                                $('span.result').data('imported',parseInt($('span.result').data('imported'))+1);
                                $('span.result .updated').html(parseInt($('span.result .updated').html())+1);
                            }else if(response.message == 'ERROR'){
                                $('span.result').data('errors',parseInt($('span.result').data('errors'))+1);
                                $('span.result .error').html(parseInt($('span.result .error').html())+1);
                            }
                            aktval++;
                            progressbar.progressbar( "value", aktval );
                        },"json");
                    }
                });
            });
            var _custom_media = true,
            _orig_send_attachment = wp.media.editor.send.attachment;
            $('#upload_button').click(function(e) {
                var send_attachment_bkp = wp.media.editor.send.attachment;
                var button = $(this);
                _custom_media = true;
                wp.media.editor.send.attachment = function(props, attachment){
                    if ( _custom_media ) {
                        $("#upload_txt").val(attachment.url);
                    } else {
                        return _orig_send_attachment.apply( this, [props, attachment] );
                    };
                }
                wp.media.editor.open(button);
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
<?php 
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_import_all_the_products_action', 'import_products_ajax_action' );

function import_products_ajax_action() {
    //get all the data you need from the $_POST Variable like this.
    $keyname = $_POST['keyname'];
    //do whatever you need to do with the product data. Import by api, or whatever.
    //put $success to true to give the info back to the admin screen
    //in $data, you can give back additional data
    if($success){
        echo json_encode(array('message' => 'SUCCESS','data' => $data));
        die();
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('message' => 'ERROR','data' => $data));
        die();
    }
}
```